# Navigation to previous router not working in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am receiving below error when using useNavigate(-1) or window.history.back(). It was previously working without any issues.

"You are trying to block a POP navigation to a location that was not created by @remix-run/router. The block will fail silently in production, but in general you should do all navigation with the router (instead of using window.history.pushState directly) to avoid this situation."

Comment: 1. Because `this` is special in the language. 2. Because `window` is special in the browser. E.g. in Firefox, `window` is actually a getter and there is no corresponding setter.

Comment: Have you ever saw a language which you overrides `this` keywork like that?  BTW, about `this`: [*It can't be set by assignment during execution*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: 1. Because `this` is not assignable and that `this` may refer to anything  depending on the scope.  you can however do something like `this.foo = {}`. Again pls be careful about what `this` means
2. `window = {}` seems to work - because it has no setter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a value to `this` keyword during execution context, because it is immutable.

Comment: *"since it is associated with execution context and therefore it's immutable."* Why would this imply immutability? Variables are also associated with an execution context and they are mutable.

Comment: It is an operator/keyword, as said by MDN Web docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I have already edited my comment (yes, it's a keyword, no, it's not an operator). What about the other part of my comment?

Comment: It's immutable, you can't assign values to it unless you call apply or bind. Otherwise it would not throw the error OP is referencing.

Comment: I know that you cannot assign to it. I'm doubting the reason you are giving: *"since it is associated with execution context"*. As I said, variables defined inside a function are also associated with an execution context. They are mutable. So "association to an execution context" is not a reason for immutability.

Comment: Yes not my brightest english use, what I meant was that it is immutable because you can't change it during execution context. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a keyword

window is a global object